# How to check console application opened by mouse or cmd?

Tags: c#, cmd, console

Is there any way to know that a c# console application is opened by mouse (double-click) or command line (without argument)?

p/s: This code must implement in this c# console application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell if there are no arguments passed in, because args() will be empty.

You cannot tell how the application was started. You can work around this if you create a shortcut for the console app and pass in an optional parameter to say how the app was started, such as launch: shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Get the command line for cmd.exe. If double clicked then its command line will start `cmd /c` eg `cmd /c programname.exe`. This isn't foolproof (a user could type it) but mostly true.

This is VBScript using COM. C# has access via interop (plus .NET also has it's own access)

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")

For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox objItem.ProcessID & " " & objItem.CommandLine
    If objItem.name = "Calculator.exe" then objItem.terminate
Next
```

Comment: I used Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() but I can not get the arguments which you said. Could you please tell the way to get them?